# Correct way to check for vendors Ex. webkitRequestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript

I got this code from Google (https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery):

```
var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame || webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
```

How is this valid? If requestAnimationFrame is not defined, the javascript will crash before it gets to check moz, webkit, or ms.

Shouldn't it be:

```
var raf =   
typeof requestAnimationFrame !== 'undefined' ? requestAnimationFrame :
typeof mozRequestAnimationFrame !== 'undefined' ? requestAnimationFrame :
typeof webkitRequestAnimationFrame !== 'undefined' ? requestAnimationFrame :
typeof msRequestAnimationFrame!== 'undefined' ? requestAnimationFrame : null;
```

Comment: *Where* did you find this code?  Was it from Google's API docs or was it just a random (how do you know if it's trustworthy) link?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I put the link up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've seen is to prefix `window.` before each of the variables.  JavaScript will throw an error if you try to access an undefined *variable*, but not an undefined *property* on an object.

```
var raf = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
```

Comment: Using this I no longer get errors on IE7...but I am getting different performance results between requestAnimation and window.requestAnimation. Aren't they equal???

Comment: Using window.requestAnimationFrame Google deducts "speed performance points" but not for requestAnimationFrame. I thought they were the same.  This is probably out of scope for this question.  Thanks.

Comment: Those "speed performance points" are probably because `a` is *slightly* faster than `window.a`, but in your case `a` might not exist.  I'd just ignore it here.